# Pytorch GPU utilization does not match model number of parameters

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

I'm running occupancy tests with an empty GPU, and when I move the following PyTorch module to the GPU (cuda:1), it occupies `843 MiB` according to NVIDIA SMI:

I can't make sense of it; the module is trivial.

This happens even with a freshly created script that creates a Linear layer and moves it to the GPU:

```
>>> Linear(1, 3).to("cuda:1")
Linear(in_features=1, out_features=3, bias=True)
```

Can anyone explain why such a simple operation results in such high GPU memory usage?